# Getting exited with error code 132 when setting up yugabyte on docker

Tags: yugabytedb

I am new to yugabyte and trying to set it up exactly using the docker installation guide but the container keeps exiting with code 132 using both docker run and docker compose

Comment: If you are running Linux, an exit code of 132 might be caused by a signal (SIGILL, illegal instruction IIRC). When a process dies because of a signal, the exit code will be 128 + signal number. Check `kill -l` to find the symbolic name of the signal